# Ubuntu HP laptop getting overheated while playing DOTA 2

Tags: nvidia, games, overheating

I am running DOTA 2 on lowest graphics and with GPU enabled and the temp is getting (I am not joking) 90-95 °C. What to do it's getting too hot!

My Laptop specs:

- processor: Intel i3 3rd gen
- Ram: 4 GB
- GPU: Nvidia 850 m (1gb)

Comment: Sound like your laptop need its innerts cleaned (dust).

Answer (score 0):

Please note the following answer is taken from [HP themselves](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01657439), and is not written by me. Please read the whole article before you do **ANYTHING.**
Information to read:

> ***WHAT IS OVERHEATING?***
>   Heat buildup can cause problems for any laptop (notebook). Generally, when temperatures inside the case rise above 35 degrees Celsius (95 degrees Fahrenheit), the risk of damaging important internal components increases greatly. The most common cause of overheating is the accumulation of dust inside the laptop. The electrical components in a notebook generate heat and fans inside the notebook help move the air to keep the components cooled to normal operating temperatures. Inadequate cooling can cause excess heat to build up inside the case which can damage components. The sound of the fan running constantly may indicate that the laptop is getting hot and is not running as efficiently as possible and that there is a problem with accumulated dust clogging the air vents.

Location of vents:

> ***Step 1: WHERE ARE MY VENTS?***
>   Most notebook computers have vents located around the case to allow air to flow through the case. If these vents become clogged, or if heat-generating parts become covered with dust, the fan cannot cool the components properly, because the laptop is hot and overheating becomes a problem. Lint and dust accumulation prevents air from flowing around the cooling fan blades and causes the fan to work harder and the laptop to get hot. If there is dust in the vents, you should clean the laptop by blowing out the dust from around the fan and heat shield. This prevents dust from accumulating.
>   It is not necessary to open the notebook (laptop) to clean out the dust with the canned, compressed air.
>   The following graphics show the dust accumulation on the inside of the laptop, but dust around the fans and heat shield of the laptop can be cleaned without opening the computer.

[image: Figure 1: Dust Accumulation]

[image: Figure 2: Dust Accumulation around a vent]

[image: Figure 3: Side Vents]

[image: Figure 4: Bottom Vents]

> ***Step 2: ENSURING PROPER SPACE FOR VENTILATION*** 
>   To decrease the likelihood of overheating problems, ensure the fans on your laptop are able to ventilate properly. Proper ventilation for the system is important for laptop operation. Follow these guidelines to ensure adequate ventilation:
>   Keep the laptop upright and on a sturdy, level surface.
>   Provide at least 15.25 centimeters (6 inches) of clearance around each vent.
>   If the laptop is being used at very high altitudes, above 1500 meters (5000 feet), take extra care to keep the laptop cool. The maximum limit of 35 degrees Celsius (95 degrees Fahrenheit) drops 1 degree Celsius (~34 degrees Fahrenheit) every ~300 meters (1000 feet) of altitude.
>
> ***Step 3: UPDATING THE BIOS.***
>   After releasing a laptop, HP regularly provides updates for the BIOS and other components. Check for BIOS updates and install them using instructions in the HP support document [Updating the BIOS](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00042629).
>
> ***Step 4: USING HP COOLSENSE TECH.***
>   HP CoolSense technology is a feature in some HP notebook (laptop) computers that combines hardware, software, and mechanical design to dynamically manage the temperature of your laptop computer. HP CoolSense uses a motion sensor in your laptop to sense when your laptop is being used in a stationary or mobile setting, and automatically adjusts the laptop performance and fan speed to keep the computer cool. You can set HP CoolSense software to your specifications. For more information, see [HP Notebook PCs - HP CoolSense Technology.](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02638953)
>
> ***Step 5: PLACE THE NOTEBOOK IN A COOLER ROOM***
>   If your laptop is overheating, place it in a cooler room. A small difference in temperature might be all that is needed to prevent a component from failing. Move the laptop to a cooler room in the house or office. If this is not an option, continue with the next step.
>
> ***Step 6: TESTING FOR HARDWARE FAILURE.***
>   If overheating issues persist after cleaning the vents and moving the computer to a cooler room, a hardware component might be damaged. Test the computer to see if any hardware, such as memory, the processor, or the graphics hardware, have failed. Most HP and Compaq notebook computers have diagnostic software to verify hardware failures. For more information, see the appropriate document:

- [Testing for Hardware Failures (Windows 10, 8)](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c03467259)
- [Testing for Hardware Failures (Windows 7)](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01895819)
- [Checking Your Notebook PC Using the HP System Health Scan for laptops running Windows Vista](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00372177)
- If hardware has failed, either replace the bad component or contact HP for further assistance using the Contact Support tab at the top of this screen.